# How can I better track Google Image Search traffic in Google Analytics? [specifically keywords]

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

So I run [HotelsFirst.com](http://www.hotelsfirst.com) and have recently seen a bunch of Google Image Search traffic
http://screensnapr.com/v/Rm1KdJ.png -- the problem is I have no way of finding what kind of searches people are doing to get to my site.  There are a bunch of different landing pages so it must be a lot of things.   I found something that seems kind of useful at http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=4f166221a4857871&hl=en however I am using a different version of Google Analytics so that doesn't work for me.  My javascript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-19201482-3']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it (since I don't have any pages off-hand that are linked to in Google Images), but this is how that script you linked to would be adapted to your snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-19201482-3']);

var ref = document.referrer;
if (ref.search(/images.google/) != -1 && ref.search(/prev/) != -1) {
    var regex = new RegExp("images.google.([^\/]+).*&prev=([^&]+)");
    var match = regex.exec(ref);
    _gaq.push(['_clearOrganic']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic',"images.google."+ match[1],"q"]);
    _gaq.push(['_setReferrerOverride', "http://images.google." + match[1] + unescape(match[2]) ]);
}
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
/* ]]> */
</script>
```